# Extract images through database

Tags: c#, sql, database, image, extract

I am working on Extracting images from a database(SQL Server 2008)
I im using a WPF application , using the Grid_Loaded event to load pages.
The examples i have found are mainly using the combo box to select the ID of an image and displaying it. However i do not want to use the combo box.

I have a few lines of code i have worked on and found on the internet, will be appreciated if someone helps me!

```
private void LoadImages()
    {
        try
        {

            string connstr = @"Server=CTGPJLPC21\SQLEXPRESS;Database=testing;Trusted_Connection=True;";
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connstr))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM test_table", conn))
                {
                    dset = new DataSet();
                    adapter.Fill(dset);
                }
                DataTable dt = dset.Tables[0];
                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    if (dset.Tables[0].Rows.Count == 1)
                    {
                        byte[] data = (byte[])dset.Tables[0].Rows[0][0];

                        MemoryStream strm = new MemoryStream();

                        strm.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                        strm.Position = 0;

                        System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(strm);

                        BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();

                        bi.BeginInit();

                        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

                        img.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);

                        ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                        bi.StreamSource = ms;

                        bi.EndInit();

                        myImg.Source = bi;
                    }
                }
                }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
long bufferSize = dataReader.IsDBNull(1) ? 0 : dataReader.GetInt64(1);
if (bufferSize > 0)
{
    j.PictureContent = new byte[bufferSize];
    bufferSize = dataReader.GetBytes(1, 0, j.PictureContent, 0, Convert.ToInt32(bufferSize));
}
```

Where j is a class instance and j.PictureContent is a byte[].